# Erasing elements in std::tr1::unordered_map

Tags: c++, unordered-map

Can we use forward iteration to erase elements in unordered_map ?

```
unordered_map<string, int> employeeTable;
unordered_map<string, int>::iterator it;

for (it = employeeTable.begin(); it != employeeTable.end();) {
   int age = it->second;
   if (age < 18) {
      employeeTable.erase(it++);
   } else {
      ++it;
   }
}
```

If the above is incorrect, what does the standard recommend ? Something like below

```
it = employeeTable.erase(it);
```

Comment: i think the erase fails there because you are advancing a deleted iterator. try copying it, advancing one copy, and deleting the other (in that order).

Comment: Could you post a complete minimal program that demonstrates the error? Also, would you provide the exact text of the error message (if any)? See http://SSCCE.ORG for more details.

Comment: Your code [works for me](http://ideone.com/TYfeh).

Comment: @user1708860 - "*try copying it, advancing one copy, and deleting the other (in that order)*". That is precisely what his code does.

Comment: @cached - you have accepted an answer that says your code above is OK.  But you said that code  <== FAILS HERE!!!!  So which is it - does the code you asked the question about fail, or does it work?

Comment: Sorry, edited. The code was failing for a different reason, however my original impression was due to this line (employeeTable.erase(it++);). That's why I raised this question to get it clarified. I approved the answer primarily due to the tr1 reference (paragraph 12), which was spot on.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to 6.3.1 [tr.unord.req] paragraph 12:

> ... The erase members shall invalidate only iterators and references to the erased elements.

That is, the code above should be OK.

Comment: Actually, the expression `it++` needs to be evaluated prior to the `erase()` because the result of the `it++` is required as the argument to `erase(). Thus, the iterator is incremented prior to the `erase()` and stays valid or has become `employeeTable.end()`. Thus, the code is OK.

Comment: Okay only in the sense that it works. It's still bad in that the OP is getting used to bad habits, and it's prone to error: e.g. sometime in the future when he comes along and decides he wants a different collection type that this fails for.

Comment: Thanks Dietmar for the tr1 reference.

Comment: @Hurkyl And in which way is this a bad habit? For which container type would this ever fail? Well ok, for a `std::vector` (and other invalidating containers), but then again an `erase`-loop for such a container is rubbish in the first place and the whole question would be invalid. Of course we could refrain from any language constructs that do *"black magic"* (like advancing and iterator and *"magically"* returning the unadvanced iterator) but this wouldn't leave much of C++'s expressiveness.

Comment: @Hurkyl And the iterator invalidation rules of containers are far from being brittle detail knowledge, it would be like not knowing the difference between C++ and ++C, oh wait.

Comment: @Christian: Your reply is boggling: rather than use the feature of the container abstraction that does specifically the desired operation, you are advocating an alternate method that requires one to consult the fine print to be confident that it's valid in this case, to engage in ridiculous rhetoric in order to ignore the situations where it's invalid, and involves a gratuitous copy to boot.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, your question contains the correct answer:

```
it = employeeTable.erase(it);
```

Comment: `std::undordered_map::erase(std::unordered_map::iterator)` returns `void`. http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map/erase

Comment: @Rob is correct about the std. My mistake was based on the Microsoft-specific documentation/implementation of returning an iterator. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb982400%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: You need to update your reference: According to 6.3.4.4 [tr.unord.map] paragraph 3 `erase()` returns an `iterator` or a `const_iterator` (depending on what type is passed in). The standard changed the signature of `erase()` to always take a `const_iterator` and to always return an `iterator`. Neither the standard nor TR1 return `void` from any of the `erase()` members.

Comment: From the link by @Rob, C++11 has changed the return type from iterator to void.  If so, my answer will not work with C++11.  I'm still not sure we have an understanding of why    employeeTable.erase(it++); didn't work for the OP.

Comment: No, the information in the reference pointed to by @Rob is wrong. `std::unordered_map::erase(std::unordered_map::iterator)` returns `iterator`. Look it up in the C++11 standard, not a secondary reference.

Comment: @PeteBecker: Damn, it's hard to follow-up because it seems someone has already edited the wiki page to include both the incorrect AND the correct version :p

Comment: @ChristianRau: Ah thanks, I tried to but could not figure out how. Much more readable now!

Comment: @DietmarKühl - I concur. §25.5.4.1/3 from draft n3290 (I don't have the official standard yet) agrees with you.